# How to add textbox value to array on click of button in angularjs and add required functionality

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi now with this code I am able to add the text box value to array and empty the textbox after adding the value to the array. Now my question on adding the required validation for the textbox. If value is present either in textbox or in the array then required validation should be removed. Else it should be added. Kindly help me.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input ng-disabled="$parent.BuildModel.DisableControl" type="text" class="form-control textBoxStyle " name="Logpath" ng-model="$parent.BuildModel.Logpath" id="Logpath" required />
        <span class="input-group-addon ">
            <button ng-click="onclickfun();">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <span ng-disabled="$parent.BuildModel.DisableControl" class="help-block" name="LogPaths" id="LogPaths" ng-model="$parent.BuildModel.LogPaths" >{{LogPaths}}</span>
```

In controller

```
$scope.BuildModel.LogPaths = [];
$scope.onclickfun = function () {
    if ($scope.BuildModel.LogPath.length < 0) {
        Alertify.alert("Please enter log path for adding to list");
    }
    $scope.BuildModel.LogPaths.push($scope.BuildModel.LogPath);
    console.log($scope.BuildModel.LogPaths);
    $scope.BuildModel.LogPath = ClientConfig.EMPTY;          
    $scope.BuildModel.res = $scope.BuildModel.LogPaths.join(' ');
};
```

Comment: you are emptying it before pushing to array;  `$scope.BuildModel.LogPath = "";`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$parent` but you don't need to use it. I have created a simple example for do that. You can see the example in [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/10060/)

html

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LogController">
    <input ng-model="inputData"></input>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="addPath()" value="add"></input>
    <div ng-repeat="log in logs">{{ log }}</div>
</div>
```

controller

```
function LogController($scope) {
    $scope.logs = [];
    $scope.addPath = function () {
        $scope.logs.push($scope.inputData);
        $scope.inputData = null;
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. But even if I give the $scope.inputData = null; the value in the textbox is not becoming empty. Push operation is working fine now.

Comment: Hi now  I am to push the value to array and also empty the textbox after it is added to array. But now I need to add required condition for the textbox field. Its like the user can enter one value in the text box or he can add more value using the add button. The required should be enabled when no value is present in both the fields. Even in one if it is present it should remove the required functionality. Kindly help me.